# PhoneGap Build + Facebook Plugin - iOS App Crashes when posting to wall w/ PG 2.5.0 (worked w/ 2.2.0)

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

**See below:** I've been able to recreate the problem with the [Simple](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/tree/master/example/Simple) and [Hackbook](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/tree/master/example/HackBook) examples.

My iOS app's facebook integration was working just great with PhoneGap 2.2.0. Once I updated the app to Phonegap 2.5.0 I started having this issue. I am able to login to facebook just fine from my app, but my app crashes as soon as I try to post something to my wall. This was not an issue before 2.5.0.

I have uploaded both the [Simple](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/tree/master/example/Simple) and [Hackbook](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/tree/master/example/HackBook) examples using my Facebook App ID to PhoneGap Build to figure out what is going on. I uploaded both examples with 2.2.0 and everything works. I then uploaded both with 2.5.0 and everything works except when I try to post to my wall or a friend's wall - the app crashes.

**The only variable I changed was `2.2.0` to `2.5.0` in the `config.xml` file.**

I've also asked this question on [PhoneGap Builds support page](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/facebook_plugin_app_crashes_when_posting_to_wall_with_pg_2_5_works_fine_with_pg_2_2_other_facebook). So, you can go there to see what others have said.

Thank you for any help you can offer!

**Additional Crash Info I got from the console:**

```
May 18 12:23:32 Marks-iPhone HackBook[9813] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary removeObjectForKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x344e62a3 0x3c18b97f 0x344e61c5 0x3446d06b 0xef831 0x1444b7 0x14416f 0x143ee5 0x143fc7 0x143f49 0x34dfd0f5 0x344bb683 0x344baee9 0x344b9cb7 0x3442cebd 0x3442cd49 0x37ff02eb 0x36342301 0xee377 0xee350)

May 18 12:23:33 Marks-iPhone ReportCrash[9830] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process HackBook[9813]

May 18 12:23:33 Marks-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.markrummel.stay4credits[0x726b][9813]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.markrummel.stay4credits[0x726b]) Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap: 6

May 18 12:23:33 Marks-iPhone backboardd[26] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.markrummel.stay4credits[0x726b]' exited abnormally with signal 6: Abort trap: 6

May 18 12:23:34 Marks-iPhone ReportCrash[9830] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
```

Comment: This might already be resolved. If so, the issue is that PhoneGap Build is using an older version of the Facebook Plugin. Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961475/phonegap-facebook-plugin/15008000#15008000. I'm going to wait to close this until I get it working in my app, just in case it is something else.